# Can anyone help me with what hidden test cases I am missing for the alphabet rangoli?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

```
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    alphalist = list(alphabet)
    size = int(input('enter size:'))
    dash = 2*size
    iter = size
    list_reverse = []
    rangoli_final = []
    while not (dash<0 and iter <0):
        dash -=2
        string = '-'*dash + '-'.join(alphalist[iter-1:size])
        if string != '':
            list_reverse.append(string)
        iter -=1
    for rangoli in list_reverse:
        rangoli_final.append(rangoli[:-1] +rangoli[::-1])  
    for val in rangoli_final[:len(rangoli_final)-1]:
        print(val)   
    for mirror in rangoli_final[::-1]:
        print(mirror)
```

It works fine in vscode but there were apparently some hidden tests for which it did not work.

Comment: It looks like you are referring to some code challenge? Which is it? Without description we cannot know what your code is supposed to do. Rangoli is a type of Indian folk art.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.